# list index out of range error while reading csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have this code where I am reading a csv file, using `NamedTemporaryFile` to change the contents of the csv file.

```
def update_localcsv():

    ping = ["Yes","No"]
    filename = 'file1.csv'
    tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode= 'w',delete=False)

    with open(filename, 'rt') as csvFile, tempfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        writer = csv.writer(tempfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

        for row in reader:

            print(row)
            row[0] = random.choice(ping)

            curr_time = datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%I:%M %p')
            row[1] = str(curr_time)
            print('current time: '+str(curr_time))
            print("New ping status = " + str(row))
            writer.writerow(row)

    shutil.move(tempfile.name, filename)
```

When I run this code I can see `print(row)` printing `['Yes', '04:23 PM']` but then it throws `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` error at `row[0] = random.choice(ping)`.

This is the current content in my csv file:

```
Yes,04:23 PM
```

Why is this error coming?

**NOTE:** When I do `print(type(row))` I get `<class 'list'>`. I also see an empty row getting printed:

```
['Yes', '04:23 PM']
current time: 05:03 PM
New ping status = ['Yes', '05:03 PM']
[]
```

Comment: Re check if type(row) is a list.

Comment: @rakshith1124 when I do `print(type(row))` I get `<class 'list'>`

Comment: create a new list and append the values instead

Comment: Do this instead: `print('Row:', row)`. I bet you will see an extra empty row after the first line.

Comment: @DarnellMartin. Figure out what the problem is so you can avoid it before you move on to something better.

Comment: OP, I was able to reproduce your issue, but I came to the conclusion that you are giving us very misleading information. Please provide your **FULL** printout! You should be able to see the problem by reading your own output carefully.

Comment: @DarnellMartin. Strangely enough, your advice would have produced an unexpected output, which would potentially lead the OP to figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist When I do print('Row:', row) I see an extra empty row after the firs line. I think there is an empty row coming in my csv file. How do I remove that? Also I am not giving any misleading info. That's the code I have exactly line by line

Comment: @user2916886. Post the full output and what you just told me into the question. It is relevant information without which your question is not complete.

Comment: Per [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader) you should open the file with `newline=''` in Python 3 (or `'rb'` in Python 2).  The module does it's own line management.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have posted the info in my post above

Comment: @MarkTolonen. Usually a good idea, but overkill in this case, if you read the bottom of the page: "If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling."

Comment: @user2916886. Thanks, overly pedantic close vote retracted.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I added `newline = ''` but still same issue

Comment: @user2916886. `newline=''` has nothing to do with your issue. It's just a good practice in general because it allows you to have newlines within CSV fields. I believe my answer covers your issue though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know how it works, it's just good practice to read and follow the documentation, and without an [mcve] it *could* have been the issue.

Comment: OP, see my edits. It is crucial to provide complete information when you ask questions like this. Notice that I updated your text file and provided a full output. Luckily I was able to dig the problem out because I suspected what the answer was. In future cases, please be precise. You would never get an answer to something a little more complex if you provided incomplete information like this.

Comment: @MarkTolonen. I am not disagreeing with you, and I apologize if I sounded condescending. My main rant here is against OP providing incomplete or outright wrong information.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I understand your rant but don't start accusing everyone of providing wrong or incomplete information. If I would have known that there's an empty line coming in at the end of my csv file I would have posted that info at the first place itself. I didn't provided any wrong or incomplete info. Not knowing an info does not mean hiding something or providing wrong info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error you are seeing by adding a newline at the end of my CSV file. I have taken the liberty of editing your question accordingly.

There are a few simple solutions. The most obvious would be to remove the trailing newline at the end of the file.

An more robust would be to skip any empty rows, or rows that do not have the two columns you require. You would still probably want to pass them through to the output writer, so you could do this (print statements omitted):

```
if len(row) == 2:
    row[0] = random.choice(ping)
    curr_time = datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%I:%M %p')
    row[1] = str(curr_time)
writer.writerow(row)
```

If you want to remove empty lines, you can add a separate case for that:

```
if row:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Since empty arrays are falsy, they will not be passed through.

Comment: What if I want to remove the trailing empty newline? Since my file will always have one row that I posted above so I don't need the trailing empty newline. How can I skip it and thus avoid adding it to the updated new file?

Comment: @user2916886. Updated answer

Comment: I checked the updated answers just now and so I accepted it just now.